# Swagger integration into Bot Framework 4

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, botframework, startup

I'm trying to integrate swagger / swashbuckler into a project with UI into a project based on the latest Bot Framework V4 template. However it seems I'm getting only 500 http status codes when I try to navigate to /swagger or /swagger/v1/swagger.json.

The things I'm trying to add are in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

and in `Configure`:

```
loggerFactory = loggerFactory;

        app.UseDefaultFiles()
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseBotFramework();

        app.UseSwagger()
            .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });
```

I also tried to put the UseSwagger parts before the other but then the bot didn't work anymore as well. Likely there's some collision in endpoints being generated by the different parts but I'd really like to get that swagger part working.

Comment: Do you see why the 500 errors? swagger would only work if every endpoint is valid as a rest API. For instance, all requests should allow only 1 HTTP verb

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Swagger requires MVC features to work and it looks like you're using the default templates for a bot which don't actually need MVC so it's not added to avoid the massive overhead that feature brings to the table.

So, you need to add the following in `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddMvc();
```

And then the following to `Configure`. NOTE: The order of the `UseXXX` calls do matter, but the order you're doing them in right now is fine and I would just do this:

```cs
app.UseDefaultFiles()
    .UseStaticFiles()
    .UseBotFramework()
    .UseMvc()
    .UseSwagger()
    .UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });
```

Comment: using this would still not provide the bot framework's endpoints on swagger will it?

Comment: Not out of the box, no. You can obviously describe the endpoint yourself. May I ask why you think you'd want the endpoint to be described? It's possible to create an extension for Swagger that would expose it, but it's kind of tied specifically to being consumed only by the Bot Framework Service.... for example it's secured in a specific way for BFS as well. I wouldn't expect people to just walk up to the bot's endpoint and pass messages into it. If u want people to invoke behaviors within your bot u probably want a companion web service to go along w/it which u would write as a controller.

Comment: Mainly asked because it seemed like OPs main intention and true this didn't seem to implement it.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I'll wait for OP to clarify then. If so, then I'll just augment my answer with a more fleshed out version of the comment I just left in reply to you. Thanks! 

Comment: The bot still functions and the swagger comes up but no endpoints are retrieved. I'm going to dig deeper into this.

Comment: Well, I can save you some time, it won't show the bots endpoints by default because Swagger is based on crawling MVC conventions and Bot Builder SDK doesn't expose itself via MVC, it's exposed as a raw endpoint via the app builder. Like I said, you can always supply a fixed description if you want using the Swagger APIs, but it's also easy enough to create an extension method for Swagger that exposes the Bot's Endpoint. I'll look into building an example for this.